# Nodejs docx-merger module doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using `nodejs`, `electron` and `docx-merger` module to merge multiple docx.

Here is my code:

```
fs.readdir('resources/app/temps/buffer/', (err, bufferFiles) => {
    var bufferFilesArr = [];
    var buffFile;
    bufferFiles.forEach(bufferFile => {
    buffFile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('resources/app/temps/buffer',bufferFile), 'binary');
    bufferFilesArr.push(buffFile);
    });
    var mergedDocx = new docxMerger({}, bufferFilesArr);
    mergedDocx.save('nodebuffer', function(data){{
        fs.writeFile(path.resolve('resources/app/temps/buffer','tempOutput.docx'), data, function(err){ });
    }});
});
```

After packaging it, it gives that error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asText' of null
    at C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Local\Programs\paletten-zettel\resources\app.asar\node_modules\docx-merger\dist\merge-relations-and-content-type.js:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.mergeContentTypes (C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Local\Programs\paletten-zettel\resources\app.asar\node_modules\docx-merger\dist\merge-relations-and-content-type.js:7)
    at DocxMerger.mergeBody (C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Local\Programs\paletten-zettel\resources\app.asar\node_modules\docx-merger\dist\index.js:51)
    at new DocxMerger (C:\Users\ibrahim\AppData\Local\Programs\paletten-zettel\resources\app.asar\node_modules\docx-merger\dist\index.js:96)
    at fs.readdir (app.html:604)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:169)
```

But it gives on the first time. And then I rerun the application, it merges without error. But I don't want it to give an error.

The documentation says, it has some issues about numbering. But I'm not using numbering.

Thank you in advance.